# Open Liberty application server and jandex version

Tags: java, open-liberty, jandex

I want to improve the startup time of my Open Liberty application using Jandex, as described in https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/745421 and https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/using-jandex-ibm-websphere-liberty-setting-configuration-enable-jandex-index-reads.

However, it seems that Open Liberty (version 21.0.0.6) is using a rather old version of Jandex. I only managed to get it running with indexes that were created with com.ibm.ws.org.jboss.jandex_1.0.53.jar (containing a Jandex 2.1.2 version), while the current version is Jandex 3.0.5.

I am aware that I might upgrade to OpenLiberty 22.0.0.13 which is the latest version, but this also only contains a Jandex version 2.x.

Is there any way to have OpenLiberty use Jandex 3 version? I assume that simply replacing the com.ibm.ws.org.jboss.jandex_1.0.x.jar file with the original Jandex Jar file will lead to incompatibilities, so is there any other chance?

---

Edit 2023-01-25:
In answer to Thomas Bitonti's reply, here is an excerpt of the startup time of the application when Jandex is active, also showing how slow the Jandex operation is.

**Use case one**: Jandex disabled:
Application startup time: 31 seconds

**Use case two**: Jandex enabled, first start.
Application startup time: 35 seconds

Number of Jars and classes according to OLP Jandex log:

> I CWWKC0093I:
> Jandex coverage of module e2e-leasing-ui-war in application
> e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 131 out of 298 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 5,118 out of 48,102 module
> classes.

*a more detailed log of use case 2 follows at the end of the question*

**Use case three:** Jandex enabled, second start.
Application startup time: 33 seconds

According to the log, the read process of indexes is somehow different, especially if you look at the first line. That might be due to the custom cache mentioned by Thomas?

```html
[1/25/23 23:35:37:730 CET] 00000030 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module e2e-leasing-ui-war in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 298 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 0 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:35:38:562 CET] 00000030 org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl     I registering MBean org.apache.cxf:bus.id=e2e-leasing-ui-war-Server-Bus,type=Bus,instance.id=1043806874: org.apache.cxf.bus.ManagedBus@6a547ce6
[1/25/23 23:35:38:572 CET] 00000030 org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl     I registered org.apache.cxf:bus.id=e2e-leasing-ui-war-Server-Bus,type=Bus,instance.id=1043806874
[1/25/23 23:35:38:610 CET] 00000030 org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl     I registering MBean org.apache.cxf:bus.id=e2e-leasing-ui-war-Server-Bus,WorkQueueManager=Bus.WorkQueueManager,type=WorkQueueManager,instance.id=154287288: org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.WorkQueueManagerImplMBeanWrapper@ee8e0e7
[1/25/23 23:35:38:886 CET] 00000030 org.jboss.weld.Version                                       I WELD-000900: 3.1.4 (Final)
[1/25/23 23:35:39:902 CET] 00000030 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/classgraph-4.8.78.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 0 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:35:39:924 CET] 00000030 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/jrap-commons-config-startup-2.123.13.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 3 out of 3 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:35:39:927 CET] 00000030 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/jackson-defensive-2.119.1-LTS.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 0 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:35:39:929 CET] 00000030 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/termin-business-api-0.58.0.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 0 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:35:40:392 CET] 00000030 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/produktantrag-business-api-2.2.0.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 102 out of 102 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:35:40:395 CET] 00000030 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/xz-1.9.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 0 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:35:40:396 CET] 00000030 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/tika-parser-apple-module-2.3.0.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 0 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:35:40:402 CET] 00000030 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/journal-client-jrap2-1.63.1.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 17 out of 17 module classes.
...
```

I attach a more detailed (but of course abbreviated) log of **use case two**, showing that reading the Jandex index seems to take 14 seconds - a bit too long, in my opinion:

```html
[1/25/23 23:31:44:383 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module e2e-leasing-ui-war in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 131 out of 298 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 5,118 out of 48,102 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:44:955 CET] 00000028 org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl     I registering MBean org.apache.cxf:bus.id=e2e-leasing-ui-war-Server-Bus,type=Bus,instance.id=1045305938: org.apache.cxf.bus.ManagedBus@205fda98
[1/25/23 23:31:44:965 CET] 00000028 org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl     I registered org.apache.cxf:bus.id=e2e-leasing-ui-war-Server-Bus,type=Bus,instance.id=1045305938
[1/25/23 23:31:45:013 CET] 00000028 org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl     I registering MBean org.apache.cxf:bus.id=e2e-leasing-ui-war-Server-Bus,WorkQueueManager=Bus.WorkQueueManager,type=WorkQueueManager,instance.id=1435508220: org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.WorkQueueManagerImplMBeanWrapper@2d8d0bdb
[1/25/23 23:31:45:270 CET] 00000028 org.jboss.weld.Version                                       I WELD-000900: 3.1.4 (Final)
[1/25/23 23:31:46:295 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/classgraph-4.8.78.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 228 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:304 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/jrap-commons-config-startup-2.123.13.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 3 out of 3 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:313 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/jackson-defensive-2.119.1-LTS.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 30 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:320 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/termin-business-api-0.58.0.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 19 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:323 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/produktantrag-business-api-2.2.0.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 102 out of 102 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:325 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/xz-1.9.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 0 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:334 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/tika-parser-apple-module-2.3.0.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 25 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:339 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/journal-client-jrap2-1.63.1.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 17 out of 17 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:344 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/vorbis-java-tika-0.8.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 8 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:353 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 22 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:387 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/jsoup-1.11.3.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 248 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:435 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/efw-services-jrap-drb-client-1.0.0.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 351 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:438 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/jrap-commons-bankdaten-1.7.16.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 19 out of 19 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:445 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/pdfbox-tools-2.0.15.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 29 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:451 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/e2e-leasing-ui-services-5.36.12-SNAPSHOT.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 185 out of 185 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:463 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/boilerpipe-1.1.0.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 76 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:469 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/json-20141113.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 31 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:474 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/sbi-commons-security-1.7.0.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 6 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:508 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/httpcore-4.4.4.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 254 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:589 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module null in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 587 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:616 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/fontbox-2.0.15.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 157 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:620 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/jrap-zsvz-client-jrap2-3.0.1.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 15 out of 15 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:623 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/discovery-service-client-jaxrs-jrap2-1.63.1.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 7 out of 7 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:635 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/crm-services-client-3.38.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 684 out of 684 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:46:639 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/kundendokumente-services-client-jrap1-1.5.8.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 181 out of 181 module classes.classes.
...
[1/25/23 23:31:53:809 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module null in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 117 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:53:813 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/jrap-soa-jca-2.123.21.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 122 out of 122 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:53:818 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module null in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 48 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:53:820 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/jrap-soa-ui-services-2.123.21.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 5 out of 5 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:53:827 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 2 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:53:829 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/wiedereinstieg-business-client-jaxrs-jrap2-2.2.0.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 1 out of 1 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:53:834 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/e2e-ng-business-jaxrs-ui-12.15.0.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 231 out of 231 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:53:835 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module null in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 0 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:53:837 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/user-service-api-1.51.10.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 58 out of 58 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:53:839 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/e2e-security-1.103.0.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 11 out of 11 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:53:841 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/discovery-service-discovering-jaxrs-jrap2-1.63.1.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 1 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 0 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:53:846 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 28 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:53:958 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module null in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 587 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:53:967 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module null in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 68 module classes.
  
...
[1/25/23 23:31:58:558 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/termin-business-api-0.58.0.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 0 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:58:559 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/jackson-defensive-2.119.1-LTS.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 0 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:58:564 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/jrap-commons-config-startup-2.123.13.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 0 module classes.
[1/25/23 23:31:58:568 CET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.annocache                                         I CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module /WEB-INF/lib/classgraph-4.8.78.jar in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 0 out of 1 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 0 out of 0 module classes.
```

Comment: The doc here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=liberty-improving-application-startup-in says "Liberty supports Jandex V2.0.3" .  So I would assume you should be able to generate the app index using v2.0.3 without modifying the runtime.   It looks like there's an open issue to investigate Jandex 3 support: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/21592.   In case that helps...

Comment: Well although the docs say so, I currently cannot find an Open Liberty version with a Jandex version 2.0 or higher...

Comment: But I don't think you should equate the version number embedded within the com.ibm.ws.org.jboss.jandex_x.y.z.jar filename with the version needed to generate the application index.   That's not what you're doing is it?

Comment: What I did is that I created an indexed Jar file with Jandex 2.0, and tried to use that Jar in OpenLiberty 21.0.0.6. It complained that it cannot read the index. When I created the index with Jandex 1.0.53, it worked, but the performance improvement was poor. I was hoping that would improve with a newer Jandex version

Comment: @ScottKurz you were right, com.ibm.ws.org.jboss.jandex_1.y.z.jar indeed contains a Jandex 2.x version. I have updated my question to reflect this. I'm not sure why using a pure Jandex 2.x version did not work, it only worked when I created the index with com.ibm.ws.org.jboss.jandex. Might have been due to some totally unrelated issue...

Answer (score 1):

Open Liberty currently reads Jandex indexes in preference to doing a scan when discovering application annotations.  The current code *should* be able to read index formats up to the latest V2 (2.4.3.Final) Jandex version.  Can you provide a sample JAR + Jandex 2 index which isn't being read?

Up to at least v23.0.0.2, Open Liberty does not read Jandex 3 indexes.

---

From a performance perspective, there are several cases:

1. Starting an application for the first time, with no Jandex indexes.
2. Starting an application for the first time, with Jandex indexes.
3. Starting an application for the second (or subsequent) time, with or
   without Jandex indexes.

The first case is slowest.  In this case, Liberty uses ASM to scan the entire application.  Liberty does its best to scan quickly, but, inherently, the scan is costly since all application classes must be read and examined.

The second case is faster.  In this case, Liberty does a special read of the Jandex indexes.  This is not quite as fast as reading the Liberty internal index format, but should be faster than doing a whole new scan (the first case).

The third case will be fastest.  In this case, Liberty reads annotations data from a custom cache format which is tuned to the Liberty annotations discovery requirements.

(There are other cases relating to restarts after making application updates.)

For your testing, can you provide information about the size of the application (counting JARs and classes), and can you provide information about the timing for the three cases, above?  I can review this to see if the times match the expected performance.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I'm reviewing the added information.

Answer (score 0):

Can you say what Jandex 2 version was used?  Definitely, Jandex 3 indexes are not currently being read.  All Jandex 2 version indexes should be read.  I'll see if I can reproduce the index read failure.

For a startup with those counts of classes, using Jandex for just over 10% of the classes (5,118 out of 48,102 module classes) will mean a first startup will still be dominated by raw scans.

A second or subsequent start really *should* be faster.  (Excepting very unusual cases: Say, an application with over 500 very small JAR files, in which case the overhead of managing the cache data becomes large.)

Can you see what data is generated in the annotations cache?

That should be a file set under the server work area, with application, module, and jar specific folders.  For example:

```
wlp/usr/servers/test/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/43/data/anno/A_simpleApp_A/M_simpleApp_M

wlp/usr/servers/<serverName>/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/<bundleNumber>/data/anno/A_<APP_NAME>_A/M_<MODULE_NAME>_M/...
```

The bundle number varies, but is usually in the 40's.  The key directory is "anno".

If you are interested, these are the trace specifications for annotation caching:

```
com.ibm.ws.annocache
com.ibm.ws.annocache.query
com.ibm.ws.annocache.state
com.ibm.ws.annocache.jandex
```

Note that some of these generate a lot of output.

This trace is also useful.  Access to the annotations cache is as a container service.

```
com.ibm.ws.container.service
```

Comment: Hi, I was using Jandex 1.0.53, as I could not get it running using Jandex 2. However, I'll try again and I'll also check the annotations cache

Comment: Actually I have to correct myself. What I did was that I used the bundled Jandex Jar that comes with OLP to get the index into my Jar files:
`foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem "."){
  C:\ent\workspaces\wsp_xxx_olp\olp-image\target\liberty\wlp\lib\com.ibm.ws.org.jboss.jandex_1.0.53.jar -m $f
}`. According to the MANIFEST.MF of this Jar file, it contains Jandex 2.1.2.Final even though the Jar's name is _1.0.53.jar.

Comment: I have no put a Jandex index into ALL Jar files, so OLP now uses nearly all indexes:
`CWWKC0093I: Jandex coverage of module e2e-leasing-ui-war in application e2e_leasing2_ui_war_war: Jandex indexes were read for 296 out of 298 module locations; Jandex indexes provided 48,106 out of 48,106 module classes.` Startup  time was now 47 seconds. I'll post more information about the annotations cache separately

Comment: the 41/data/anno directory contains 4 subdirectories (for jmx connector, ws rest handler, microprofile health 3.0 internal, and my application)., And especially the folder of my application contains lots of .data and .stamp files, obviously one for each Jar file of my application

Comment: starting a 2nd time even took 68 seconds. I believe is especially because reading the indexes now takes 23 seconds, when all Jars are indexed. So it seems the more Jars I index, the slower the startup becomes...

Comment: This appears to be a problem.  I'm looping in the performance team to determine how to gather detailed performance information.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no simple way to gather additional data.  Our internal profiling tools are not public.  Maybe, jprofiler can be used, but you need a paid license.  Maybe the Java Health Center can be used, if using an IBM JDK, but the data that the health center provides is not as fine-grained as we want.
Very coarse data can be obtained by generating a number of thread dumps, say, one every 5s.  That would provide a hint of where time is being spent.

Comment: If there were a way to provide a copy of the application, we can run it by the performance team and collect detailed profile data about the startups.  I understand that that may not be allowed.
Or, we (IBM) might be able to point to a publicly available application which IBM performance has profiled, then you could time the startup of that, and that might provide insights as to what is happening.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for your efforts! I'll discuss this internally and then inform you what possibilities we see.